# Ansible - How to add rescue action for a whole playbook with multiple plays

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible version : 2.4.2.0

I have a playbook with say 4 plays

First play does locking (Creates one lock file)
Second play is for deployment logic
Third runs a test suite and waits for the result
Fourth does the rollback based on test results

Finally i would want to delete the lock file
But assume all hosts fail during deployment, the subsequent plays wont be executed.

How do i make sure my unlock play runs always for all hosts irrespective of the result of the previous plays

Comment: Please post the playbook which you have tried and if you are facing any errors. It will be helpful.

Comment: That is the default behavior. What issue are you facing?

Comment: @sakibmoon: what OP is asking for is **not** the default behaviour. Hosts that fail wherever in the playbook are not contacted anymore in the current play and the next ones.